Why is my React client with Next.js not receiving messages sent by the WebSocket on the Spring Boot backend?
I am trying to implement a WebSocket system. On the server, I correctly configured the WebSocket and the service that sends messages. The React client connects to the WebSocket without any problems, but the issue is that it cannot capture the messages sent by the server.
Here is the WebSocket configuration on the Java Spring Boot server:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications")
                .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000") // Allow frontend origin
                .withSockJS();
    }
}

@Service
public class NotificationService {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    public NotificationService(SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
    }
    
    public void sendWelcomeNotification(UserEntity loggedInUser) {
        // Notification data
        String message = "Welcome to HydroLife, " + loggedInUser.getName() + "!";
        String sender = "HydroLife";
        LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
        String profileImage = "/images/Logo3.png";
        var notification = new NotificationDTO(sender, message, timestamp, profileImage);
    
        /// Sending the notification via WebSocket to the frontend
        // Converting and sending to the specific user destination
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                loggedInUser.getEmail(),
                "/queue/notifications",
                notification
        );
    }
}

On the frontend, I am using the WebSocket client in React with Next.js to connect to the server, but it is not capturing the messages. Here’s the client code:
useEffect(() =\> {
    const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/notifications');
    const stompClient = new Client({
    onConnect: () =\> {
    console.log('Connected to WebSocket');
    
        stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notifications', (message) => {
          const notificationData = JSON.parse(message.body);
          setNotification(notificationData);
          console.log('New notification received:', notificationData);
        });
      },
    });
    
    stompClient.activate();
    
    return () => {
      if (stompClient) {
        stompClient.deactivate();
        console.log('Disconnected from WebSocket');
      }
    };

}, []);

The WebSocket connection is established successfully (the client connects to the server), but the client is not able to capture or display the messages sent by the server. The console.log inside the stompClient.subscribe is never triggered, even though the backend service is sending messages to the topic.
I’ve already checked if the server is sending the messages, and it seems to be working correctly. Why is my React client with Next.js not receiving the messages from the WebSocket on the Spring Boot backend? Is there something I might be missing or some incorrect configuration in the WebSocket communication?
